# How to update an element in a datatable result?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show gender name for data comming from a datatable.My code is

```
 dt = new data().Get_Data(Id);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            bool gender = clsCommon.ParseBool(row["Gender"].ToString());

            //if (gender)
               // row["Gender"] = "Male";

           // else
               // row["Gender"] = "Female";
        }
```

Problem is that how to find row index of gender as the number of items in the result of datatable changes depends upon the check box selected.I have to update true value as Male and vice versa.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What type is `Gender`? Do you want to update this column with a new value according to it's old value? What is the problem, why don't your out-commented code work?

Comment: I want to update row["Gender"] = "male" and by uncommenting above code following error occurs  "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

Comment: So the type of the `DataColumn` `Gender` is `bool` instead of `string`. So either change it to be `string` in the first place or use a second column for your string representation.

Comment: in which format you have save Gender value inside database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update row["Gender"] = "male" and by uncommenting above code
>   following error occurs "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

So the type of the `DataColumn` `Gender` is `bool` instead of `string`. So either change it to be `string` in the first place or use a second column for your string representation.

Assuming that `Get_Data` returns a `DataTable` which is filled from database. Then it would be the best approach to select the desired  `string` for your `bool`, for example:

```
SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, Col3, 
       CASE WHEN Gender=1 THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS Gender
FROM dbo.Data
WHERE Id = @Id
```